# mysql explain output not correct

Tags: mysql

i have very simple table structure where i am storing the music of my database as music are in different language so i am sorting the songs with column song_language .table structure is like this

> ```
>       id            title               song_language
> ```

I have 1 million approx songs in different languages but when i am trying to filter out it scans all songs of that particular language. If i say song_language='Eng' it will scan all 500000 songs however i want only 3 songs and my column song_language is nicely indexed .here is my query

```
      SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE song_language='Eng' limit 6
```

it takes 0.0009 seconds to execute so i am happy but explain says something different

```
       id   select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
       1    SIMPLE  tableA  ref     song_language   song_language   167     const   462591  Using where
```

output after order by

```
        id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
        1   SIMPLE  tableA  ref     song_language   primary     4   null    11  Using where
```

so i think it is not using indexing and when i execute this query it takes  0.0035 second against my previous query without order by took only 0.0009 second

Anyone can give some light on this strange output of explain?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP yes i am sure why u hv doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add an `ORDER BY` on that query if you are using a limit. If it is sorting on a non-indexed column it could explain the unexpected query plan.

Comment: please note that after order by indexing is of no use as it will no use index if u add order by

Comment: using LIMIT without an order by is equally useless. Also, you are incorrect. Indexes are definitely used by sorts.

Comment: when i m adding order by id explain is telling it has examined only 11 rows but key is changing to primary so i think in that case it is not using index see my updated question for explain output

Comment: You should keep in mind that it is not ALWAYS faster to use the index. The query optimizer is generally smart enough to know when to avoid using the index and is usually right.

Comment: when we use limit we should avoid using order by group by as it forces mysql to first collect all information then order the result then present and if we are not using order by it will just throw the first 6 output so it will be several times fast

Comment: Sure, if speed is more important than a meaningful result. Not sure when returning X "random" rows is all that useful.